# Angular view not refreshing after Model Change

Tags: angularjs, view, resources

Good morning all.

I have this problem that I've been struggling with for the past day. I'm working on an invoicing application and I'm having issues with the view refreshing after a model change for one of the functions.

A little background- The front end stores the entire invoice, including customer data, line items and payments in a model. When this model is changed it is passed to a back end that performs the calculations on the the invoice and returns that model back to angular. (I know its better to do calculation client side but there is a lot of business logic that needs to be applied so i moved it to the back end.) All of the calls function as expected and the view updated without any issue except one. I have a function that takes the dimensions of an object and gives the different costs using different products. The user can select which item they would like to purchase and its added to the invoice as a line item.

What working / not working -

- The view is updated with a empty line item; this is being pushed into the model via the function.
- The model is being sent to the server, being processed and returned back to the client.
- The model is not being updated on the client site nor the view.

Coffee Script:

```
$scope.addItem = (id, pop = false) ->
    if pop
      $scope.invoice.lines.push {
        'item_id': id
        'item_name': ''
        'count': $scope.cost.width + " x " + $scope.cost.height
        'cost': 0
        'sub_total': 0
      }
      $scope.invoice.time_stamp = new Date()
      tmpInv = EntryTemp.update({id: $userid}, { "invoice_data": { "data": $scope.invoice } }, (data) ->
        $scope.invoice = data
      )
    else
      tempItm = EntryItems.query({id: id}, (data) ->
        $scope.invoice.lines.push {
          'item_id': id
          'item_name': data.itemName
          'count': 0
          'cost': data.saleData.salePrice
          'sub_total': 0
        }
      )

  $scope.delItem = (item) ->
    index = $scope.invoice.lines.indexOf(item)
    $scope.invoice.lines.splice(index, 1)
    $scope.invoice.time_stamp = new Date()
    tempItm = EntryTemp.update({id: $userid}, { "invoice_data": { "data": $scope.invoice } }, (data) ->
      $scope.invoice = data
    )

  $scope.updateItem = () ->
    $scope.invoice.time_stamp = new Date()
    tempItm = EntryTemp.update({id: $userid}, { "invoice_data": { "data": $scope.invoice } }, (data) ->
      $scope.invoice = data
    )
```

The problem function is `addItem`. The `pop` variable is used to distinguish between items added from the price comparison tool and the standard menu.

I should mention that when an item is added via the normal item menu it is  pushed to the invoice model, else statement in `addItem`, but not saved. Once the user changes the count the model is sent to the server with the new line item and processed using the `updateItem` function. (this works fine)

View code: (HAML)

```
%md-table-container
  %table{"md-progress" => "promise", "md-row-select" => "", "md-table" => ""}
    %thead{"md-head" => ""}
      %tr{"md-row" => ""}
        %th{"md-column" => ""}
        %th{"md-column" => ""}
          %span Item
        %th{"md-column" => ""}
          %span Count | Size
        %th{"md-column" => ""}
          %span Unit Price
        %th{"md-column" => ""}
          %span Cost
    %tbody{"md-body" => ""}
      %tr{"md-auto-select" => "", "md-row" => "", "md-select" => "dessert", "md-select-id" => "name", "ng-repeat" => "item in invoice.lines"}
        %td{"md-cell" => ""}
          %md-button.md-icon-button{'ng-click'=>'delItem(item)'}
            %md-icon.mdi.mdi-delete
        %td{"md-cell" => ""} {{item.item_name}}
        %td{"md-cell" => ""}
          %input{'ng-model' =>'item.count', :type=>'text', 'ng-blur'=>'updateItem()'}
        %td{"md-cell" => ""} ${{item.cost}}
        %td{"md-cell" => ""} ${{item.sub_total}}
```

What I've tried --

- I've tried copying the `$scope.invoice` to `tmp` push the new line to `tmp` and send `tmp` to the data service. Once the data service is returned I apply the returned data to `$scope.invoice`. (the taught was that `$digest()` was still processing `$scope.invoice` and didn't see the second update, hence moving it to another variable.
- I've tried calling `$scope.$apply()` but i just get the `Digest is already running` error
- I've tried `$timeout` up to 2000 to delay the post function.

Any and all help would be great.

**Code based on Sam's Suggestion**
Back end updates but the view doesn't --

```
  $scope.addItem = (id, pop = false) ->
    if pop
      tmp = angular.copy($scope.invoice)
      tmp.lines.push {
        'item_id': id
        'item_name': ''
        'count': $scope.cost.width + " x " + $scope.cost.height
        'cost': 0
        'sub_total': 0
      }
      tmp.time_stamp = new Date()
      tmpInv = EntryTemp.update({id: $userid}, { "invoice_data": { "data": tmp } }, (data) ->
        $scope.invoice = data
      )
    else
      tempItm = EntryItems.query({id: id}, (data) ->
        $scope.invoice.lines.push {
          'item_id': id
          'item_name': data.itemName
          'count': 0
          'cost': data.saleData.salePrice
          'sub_total': 0
        }
      )
```

Comment: instead of sending the $scope.invoice in to update method, send the copy of it for ex. use angular.copy($scope.invoice) and try when use ngResource update method it changes the passed variable with the response it receives so it may be the problem in your case

Comment: Sam thanks for the suggestion but the view still doesn't update. I did try this before but i gave it another shoot just in case I was blinded by frustration.